# Difference between current time and UTC time format in javascript with Date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I am using `newsapi.org` to get news data and **date-fns library**. How can I get difference between **PublishedTime** of article which is **in UTC+000** (e.g: 2020-09-13T15:50:00Z) and **current datetime**?
What i have tried:

```js
import { formatDistance } from "date-fns";
timeDistance = (time) => {
  return formatDistance(new Date(), time);
};
```

where time is a string:  e.g: "2020-09-13T15:50:00Z"

Expected result: something like 10 minutes ago, 1 hour ago etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import formatDistance from 'date-fns/formatDistance';

timeDistance = (time) => {
  return formatDistance(new Date(), new Date(time));
};

console.log(timeDistance('2020-09-13T15:50:00Z'));
```

*Note: make sure you import `formatDistance` from `date-fns/formatDistance` to make code splitting easier*